# GraphQL Mutation to update an array of fields in database

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am using GraphQL. Our database has over 300 available config settings. When a user is on a page I show the config data for that page. For example if they are on the color page I would show the values for primary_color, success_color, secondary_color, accent_color etc. In the database we have basically a key field and a value field. The key would have "primary_color" and the value would be "#FF0000". This is how all the config data is saved in the database.

When user clicks save on the page I want to save any field that the user has changed. Is it possible to have a mutation that would accept an array of objects that would have the fields that have been changed on that page. So the mutation would get an array like:
[ { key: "primary_color", value: "00FF00"} ....].  The mutation would loop through all items in the array and save it to the database?

I want to have a mutation that I can use on every page to save any config values that the user changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with mutation using an object/array as 'input type'. [mutation] resolver can loop over items to update db. Probably you can use some backend specifics (sets) to update many items at once.

Just define your input type to accept an array of pair types (objects).

Querying for an array is no problem. You can query for settings:

```
 query settings(type: "color") {
   key
   value
 }
```

A little problem for optimized response size - you can not query for unknown key names to get response like `[{"primary_color":"#FF0000"}, {"success_color":"#00FF00"}]` - however it is possible using 'custom JSON type'.